# Android Studio Mojave not starting

Tags: android, android-studio, macos-mojave

I know that this is unlikely the correct place to ask, but I don't know where I should.

So I have a normal macbook from 2016.
I had Android studio installed a couple of months and worked with it just fine for a long time.
Now upgrading to Mojave, Android Studio doesn't open anymore.
I reinstalled it already 5 times, tried everything I found in the internet but still not able to start it.
After installing and moving it to applications It asks me to open it, I accept and then it starts to bounce but never opens.
I have restarted my Mac as well, tried different accounts.
Any one with same issue who solved it or has any idea how it could be solved?

Answer (score 6):

I am having the same issue and according to Android Studio's website, it seems like it only supports up to High Sierra. Scroll to the bottom of this page and look into the system requirements-> https://developer.android.com/studio/

Comment: So I have to downgrade back to high Sierra ? I am wondering because I see almost no discussion about this issue

Comment: Same here. There should have been way more discussions if it was affecting everyone. I had been able to install it later, though it seems to be quite unstable.

Comment: could you please answer @tahsin Amio?

Comment: we'd probably need to downgrade until a more stable version is released.

Comment: Thing is I am on Mojave and it works just fine.. My friend is having this issue however.

Answer (score 3):

Try to delete (or fix) your custom studio.vmoptions file (if it exists). I had the same problem, until i've noticed, that studio runnable file writes to log, that my studio.vmoptions (in my Users/myusername/Librery/Preferences/AndroidStudio directory) has wrong parameter. Then I just delete this custom studio.vmoptions - and android studio starts normally.

Comment: Mine is running just fine in a fresh install of Mojave. I think this is the issue of osx upgrades with old settings data interrupting the natural work flow. So, my bet is on this answer.